# How to import DataTables in npm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, npm

The usual way of `import "datatables.net-select";` doesn't seem to work.

I've looked on the website and it says to do:

```
var $       = require( 'jquery' );
var dt      = require( 'datatables.net' )( window, $ );
```

But I get a `Cannot set property '$' of undefined`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use like this` var $       = require( 'jquery' );
var dt      = require( 'datatables.net-dt' )();`

Comment: @Manu Still the same problem. If it helps, I'm not including the CDN via the index.html (I feel like it shouldn't need to since I'm using NPM)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured it out.

The only reason why I thought it wasn't working was because the css wasn't there. Make sure you also import the `-dt` stuff as well.

I.e:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

import 'datatables.net';
import 'datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css';
```

Comment: Why would the CSS being loaded make a difference with the error you got?

Comment: This answer no longer works with version `1.11.3`

Answer (score 5):

I'm using DataTables 1.10.19 with Symfony 4.1.7 + Webpack Encore 0.21

```
    import $ from 'jquery';
    import dt from 'datatables.net-bs';
    global.$.DataTable = dt;
```

Answer (score 3):

After much fiddling I found something that works for me.

If you look at `node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js` you can see what's going on. If you're not using AMD, it's probably going to use the `module.exports = function (root, $)` version.

So the proper way to call it is

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import setup from 'datatables.net'
window.DataTable = setup(window, $)
```

Assigning to `window.DataTable` is optional.

However, the TypeScript typings seem to assume that `datatables.net` is returning some `Api` object, to fix that, create `datatables.net.d.ts` and throw this in it:

```
declare module 'datatables.net' {
    export default function factory(root: Window, $: typeof import('jquery')): typeof import('datatables.net')
}
```

That makes the errors go away for me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
window.$ = require('jquery');
var dt = require('datatables.net');
window.$.DataTable = dt;
```

like described here https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/434